# How to add key-value sets to HashSet or overwrite if it already exists

Tags: java, key-value, hashset

So I have a working hashset but I need to add a method which takes two arguments (key string and set string) that checks if the key already exists in the HashSet and if it does, overwrite it with the new set values and if it doesn't then create it and add it the supplied values

the code I have already tried is:

```
    public void addMapEntry(String dish, Set<String> ingredient){
    recipes.get(dish);
    if (recipes.containsKey(dish)) {
        recipes.replace(dish, ingredient);
    } else {
        recipes.put(dish, ingredient);
    }
}
```

The code for the full class so far is:

```
public class Recipe {
Map<String, Set<String>> recipes;

public Recipe() {
    this.recipes = new HashMap<>();
}

public void addData() {
    Set<String> ingredients = new HashSet<>();

    ingredients.add("Rice");
    ingredients.add("Stock");
    recipes.put("Risotto", ingredients);

    ingredients = new HashSet<>();
    ingredients.add("Bun");
    ingredients.add("Patty");
    ingredients.add("Cheese");
    ingredients.add("Lettuce");
    recipes.put("Burger", ingredients);

    ingredients = new HashSet<>();
    ingredients.add("Base");
    ingredients.add("Sauce");
    ingredients.add("Cheese");
    ingredients.add("Pepperoni");
    recipes.put("Pizza", ingredients);
}

public void printMap() {
    for(String recipeKey : recipes.keySet()) {
        System.out.print("Dish : " + String.valueOf(recipeKey) + " Ingredients:");
        for (String dish : recipes.get(recipeKey)) {
            System.out.print(" " + dish + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
public void printMapValue(String a) {
    if (recipes.containsKey(a)) {
        System.out.println("The ingredients for " + a + " Are: " + recipes.get(a));
    } else {
        System.out.println("That string does not match a record");
    }
}
public void addMapEntry(String dish, Set<String> ingredient){
    recipes.get(dish);
    if (recipes.containsKey(dish)) {
        recipes.replace(dish, ingredient);
    } else {
        recipes.put(dish, ingredient);
    }
}}
```

I get the error cannot find symbol - method replace(java.lang.String,java.util.Set)

which I think means I need to add a toString() somewhere maybe!?

Comment: You didn't explain what's wrong with the code you have. Or a simple `put()` for that matter.

Comment: Sorry, I have added more information and the error I receive

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](https://ideone.com/RQuvR1) Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The `put()` method already handles the overriding and inserting case you are interested in. Just use:

```java
public void addMapEntry(String dish, Set<String> ingredient){
    recipes.put(dish, ingredient);
}
```

> The `java.util.HashMap.put()` method of `HashMap` is used to insert a mapping into a map. This means we can insert a specific key and the value it is mapping to into a particular map. **If an existing key is passed then the previous value gets replaced by the new value.** If a new pair is passed, then the pair gets inserted as a whole.

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashmap-put-method-in-java/

Comment: This was my first thought but I get compilation error when trying to use the method with error:

Recipe cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String,java.util.Set<java.lang.String>
  found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
  reason: actual argument java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.Set<java.lang.String> by method invocation conversion

Comment: This looks like you are calling this method incorrectly. Does it give you a line number?

Comment: I was creating a new instance of Recipe() by doing Recipe book1 = new Recipe();
then calling this method by doing book1.addMapEntry("Curry", "Spices");
changing it to book1.addMapEntry("Curry", Collections.singleton("Spices")); works but I can get it to work for multiple string values to make a set i.e book1.addMapEntry("Curry", Set.of("Spices", "Ghee")); is there another / better way to be calling the method?

Comment: ```java
book1.addMapEntry("Curry", "Spices"); 
```
This is the problem. It is expecting a `Set`, you are giving it a `String`. You will need to pass in a `Set` (yes, by creating one). Alternatively, you could make an [Overload](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-in-java/) method to assist.